# MySQL Stored Procedure Throwing Errors when called

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

When I create this stored procedure, I get no errors and it gets created just fine.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`portaluser`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_CreateDatabaseAndTablesByIdAndName`(
 IN p_vendorId VARCHAR(256),
 IN p_name VARCHAR(256)
)

BEGIN

SET @db_create = CONCAT('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS xx_client_', p_vendorId, '_', p_name);    
PREPARE stmt FROM @db_create;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

When I call this stored procedure, it creates the database, yet throws a warning: 1295 This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet.

```
CALL sp_CreateDatabaseAndTablesByVidAndName('11111', 'xx');
```

I can't seem to find anywhere online that tells me exactly why this is throwing an error, seeing as though it's a fairly simple query. I've seen other people do essentially the same thing without any problems. I need a second set of eyes to tell me where I'm going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

**Note: I had previously changed p_VendorId to an INT(11) and called it the following way, but still got the same error:

```
CALL sp_CreateDatabaseAndTablesByVidAndName(11111, 'xx');
```

Comment: What is your mysql version?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was because I did this:

```
END
```

Rather than:

```
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```